# How is the yellow colour of nitric acid removed?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

Nitric acid obtained in laboratory is slightly yellow due to the dissolution of nitrogen dioxide which is produced due to thermal decomposition of a portion of $\ce{HNO3}$.

$$ \ce {4HNO3  -> 2H2O + 4NO2 + O2}$$

Its says here that if $\ce{CO2}$ is bubbled through the acid, it turns colourless- because it drives out $\ce{NO2}$ from warm acid which is further oxidized to nitric acid.

What does it mean by `drives out` ? How can carbon dioxide drive out nitrogen dioxide that's dissolved in the acid? And also, the oxidation of 'what' is being talked about here?

Comment: Look up "Henrys law"

Answer (score 4):

I think you can explain this using the equilibrium:

$\ce{NO_2(g) <=> NO_2(dissolved)}$

When you pass $CO_2$ through the warm acid, the [partial pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_pressure) of $CO_2$ ($P_{CO_2}$) above the gas increases (Since partial pressure generally represents the amount of gas above the solution).

Since

1. total pressure $P = P_{NO_2} + P_{CO_2}$ ([Dalton's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton%27s_law))
2. And $P$ remains constant at atmospheric pressure (assuming that the system is not closed).

$P_{NO_2}$ will decrease.

According to [Le Chatelier's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle), the equilibrium proceeds backward to compensate the decrease in $P_{NO_2}$ and thus more $NO_2$ gas is released. The gas flows quickly along with the bubbled gas and this prevents the forward reaction.

This seems like quite a roundabout method but it works. I'm sure there could be a much simpler explanation though.

The oxidation mentioned is most probably the disproportion reaction of $NO_2$ when it comes in contact with water:

$\ce{3NO_2 + H_2O -> 2HNO_3 + NO}$